# Remove ContentIntent from Android Wear but keep it on Handheld

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'd like to remove the ContentIntent from my android wear notification (I have a separate action i'd like to use when opening app from watch), but still keep it on the handheld.  The following code sets the content intent and then ends up removing it later.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
mainNotification.setContentIntent(contentIntent)

// wearable extender to add 2nd page and extend the main notification
dualNotification =
        new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
            .extend(mainNotification)
                .extend(wearableExtendedNotification)
                .setContentIntent(null)  // thisremoves content intent that was set before
                            ;
```

I also tried using setContentAction() which would work fine but it squishes the first notification card down on the wearable so the text isn't readable.